# Redirect Web Traffic through My App Android?

Tags: android, redirect, web, webview, traffic

I want to Capture All Url of All Apps trying to visit and change Header of every Url and Go.
I mean I need to change Header of every Web Traffic in Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, this is not generally possible, except via security exploits or on rooted device. You are welcome to write a proxy server, but *users* will have to opt into using that proxy server.

Comment: Any Idea for rooted Devices?.